# JSONP request gives Unexpected token (:) but not on partner's computer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino project with another student. We are working with an Arduino Yùn module and a website powered by Angular.js.

When we wanna do a get request for the contents of the data store we do the following things:

```
var promise = $http.jsonp("http://192.168.0.234/data/get?callback=JSON_CALLBACK");

    promise.then(
        function(arduinoData) {
            console.log(arduinoData.data.value);
        }
    );
```

On my partner's computer (Windows) this works perfectly and he can work on with the data. When I do the request on my laptop (Mac) I get an error in the JavaScript console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`.

I'm absolutely puzzled what the problem could be. I'm using the exact same code with the same Angular.js version and such. It seems to me like a platform-dependent problem, but that would be extremely weird since it's basic HTTP requests and JavaScript handling...

Somehow the JSON_CALLBACK isn't recognised or something. To be honest I don't have an idea what the JSON_CALLBACK does, but on my partner's PC it works like a charm...

Whoever gives me some advice on what could be the problem gets a huge thank you and 100 internet points.

Comment: What does the raw response from that URL look like?

Comment: @Pointy It looks like this for example (when Data Store is empty): `{"value":[],"response":"get"}`.

Comment: Looks like you're using `$http.jsonp()` which expects back a function call. That's just plain JSON.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the arduino indeed gives JSON instead of JSONP, which causes it not to parse as its not expecting the colon... But I'm absolutely clueless...